¿Cuál es la frase en español para esta abreviatura informática? Es algo así como "carga máxima permitida para un avión tamaño dos"
La Pregunta CortaSin Mucha Explicación

La forma breve de la pregunta es la siguiente:

Si tradujeras DBL_MAX al español, ¿qué obtendrías?

Para la mayoría de los lectores, esta pregunta requiere alguna explicación adicional.

La Larga Explicación
Casi todas las palabras clave en el lenguaje de programación C++ son abreviaturas de palabras en inglés.
En concreto, las abreviaturas se forman eliminando letras.
Supongamos que a un estudiante universitario avanzado se le encargara escribir un programa de computadora que tradujera un nuevo lenguaje de programación a un lenguaje mucho más antiguo; el lenguaje más antiguo es "C++".
El nuevo idioma sería esencialmente una versión en español de "C++" creada para estudiantes que tienen dificultades con el inglés.
En programación informática, la palabra inglesa "double" se utiliza como abreviatura de "número de coma flotante de doble precisión".
Tenemos que DBL_MAX se forma eliminando letras de la cadena de texto DOUBLE_MAXIMUM.
In Spanish, we have something like MÁXIMO DE DOBLE, pero el español no es mi primer idioma y no estoy seguro de mi elección de palabras.
¿Cómo se escribe "el máximo del segundo tamaño"?

Esto es análogo a escribir el tamaño del segundo vaso más pequeño para bebidas en un restaurante de comida rápida.
¿Cuál es la frase en español para "nivel de llenado máximo de una taza de tamaño dos"?
El tamaño uno es el más pequeño, el tamaño dos es el segundo más grande, el tamaño tres es el tercero más grande, y así sucesivamente.
Como analogías adicionales, tenemos:

¿Cuál es el ancho de la segunda camisa más pequeña?

¿Cuál es el peso máximo de carga para el avión de carga de forma segundo?


Puede tener tres o cuatro aviones de diferentes tamaños con un número para el volumen o masa máximo de carga para cada avión.

Si deseas alejarte del lenguaje natural y aventurarte en el mundo de la programación informática, puedes leer más aquí, pero no es necesario tener conocimientos de programación para responder a esta pregunta.

Soy un programador profesional y puedo decir que es muy común mantener los nombres de variables y constantes en inglés, precisamente por la simplicidad del idioma. Si tuviera que declarar una constante en español para el máximo de carga para el segundo avión, probablemente se llamaría algo como "MAX_CARGA_SEGUNDO", "MAX_CARGA_2DO" o "MAX_CRG_2DO", aunque tiendo a no usar abreviaturas que no son estándar o claras en lenguaje coloquial, a menos que el equipo que toca el código las tenga ya como parte del dominio del problema.

Mantenerlas en inglés generalmente no representa mayor problema, tomando en cuenta que la mayoría de los programadores hablan algún nivel de este, pues los lenguajes de programación suelen tener no solo las palabras reservadas, sino un gran número de bibliotecas en este idioma. Yo tiendo a mantener todo en inglés, pues de otra forma el código termina siendo un spanglish que es más difícil de procesar.

El valor DBL_MAX está vinculado al concepto de límite.  Si buscas "límite de constantes", hallarás varias entradas que explican el concepto.  Por lo común emplean DBL_MAX tal cual, sin traducirlo.  El ejeplar que sigue es de learn.microsoft.com y da una definición de DBL_MAX.
https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-language/limits-on-floating-point-constants?view=msvc-170

En efecto, se escribe así nomás. Traducirlo haría innecesariamente lento el proceso de programar, además ya está traducido si admitimos esa abreviatura en castellano.

DBL_MAX en C++ es una constante que define el máximo tamaño de las variables de tipo numérico de doble precisión en punto flotante.
DBL_MAX viene, como bien dices de DOUBLE_MAXIMUM, en español podríamos decir algo así como MAXIMO_DOBLE o MAXIMO_DOBLE_PRECISION, que podrían reducirse a MAX_DBL o MAX_DBL_PREC
Para describir en una variable un concepto como "Máximo tamaño de elementos de tipo X en su segunda categoría" yo usaría algo como MAXIMO_TAMAÑO_TIPO_DOS o MAXIMO_TAMAÑO_TIPO_SEGUNDO que podrían simplificarse a MAX_TAM_T2.
Sin embargo en tus ejemplos hablas de niveles de llenado, volúmenes y ancho, es decir, dimensiones distintas en cada caso que, aunque relacionadas todas con el tamaño, no son exactamente lo mismo en cada caso.
Tal vez MAXIMA_DIMENSION_TIPO_DOS sería una opción más acertada, que podríamos reducir a MAX_DIM_T2

Si tuviera que traducir DBL_MAX de C++ a Ñ++ (C++ en español), seguiría el siguiente proceso:
DBL_MAX es abreviatura de DOUBLE MAXIMUM, que se puede traducir como DOBLE MAXIMO, que se puede abreviar como DBL_MAX.
Generalizando, dado un tipo llamado XXX, en español se entiende perfectamente si su valor máximo se denota mediante XXX_MAX y el mínimo con XXX_MIN.
Para la mínima diferencia vale XXX_EPSILON (si alguien no sabe para qué se usa épsilon en matemáticas, se puede dedicar a otra cosa).
Para el número de bits del tipo (WIDTH en inglés), se podría elegir XXX_ANCHO (muy literal para mi gusto) o directamente XXX_BITS o XXX_NUM_BITS.
Y para tipos de tamaño variable, no habría problema con abreviar su longitud máxima como XXX_LNG_MAX.
